# Efficient way to check if any of the prefixes stored in comma separated list is the prefix of a word

Tags: php

I have a comma separated list of prefixes stored in a variable

```
$prefixes = “fa,go,urg”;
```

and a word stored in another variable

```
$word = “good”;
```

Now I want to know efficient way to check if any of the prefixes stored in $prefixes is the prefix of $word or not.

**My intention is**

If any of the prefixes stored in $prefixes is the prefix of the word stored in $word return TRUE.

If none of the prefixes stored in $prefixes is the prefix of the word stored in $word return FALSE.

Note:- Comma separated list of prefixes is provide by user using text box.

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can be done is to have the prefixes within an array, and then check if `$word` is present within the array `$preArr` using [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

> **in_array**
>
> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>
> in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array

```
$prefixes = “fa,go,urg”;
$preArr = explode(',', $prefixes); // Convert to array

$word = “good”; 

if (in_array($word, $preArr)) {
    echo "Success!";
} else {
    echo "Failure!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Object Manipulator, comma separated list is converted to array using `in_array` function, now need to check if any prefixes stored the array `$preArr` is the prefix of `$word`. If found stop and return TRUE else return FALSE. Want to accept your answer if completed.

Comment: You simply need to mention `return true` and `return false` instead of Success and failure respectively. The logic remains the same, just change your desired return statement. :)

Comment: `in_array($word, $preArr)` will compare whole word but it must return true as prefix `go` is found in `good`.  Definition: Prefix is a word, letter, or number placed before another

Answer (score 0):

The `substr` function can achieve the desired result. It checks for the word `good` in the `prefixes` at specified location, which is the beginning of the word.

From the PHP Manual:

> > substr — Return part of a string
>
> Description
>
> `string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )`
>   Returns the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters.

Try this:

```
  $prefixes = “fa,go,urg”;
    $word = “good”;
    $Arr[] = explode(',', $prefixes); // Convert to array
    $elements = count($Arr[]);   //get total elements in array

   for ($i=0;$i<count;$i++) {
   if (substr( $Arr(i), 0, 4 ) === $word) {
   return true;
   }
   else {return false;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by a few ways, the most programmatic method being to just do a simple check, iterate across `$prefixes` and check it against 0.....i where `i = N - 1` and `N = count($prefixes[$i])`

```
function inPrefixArr($prefixes, $word) {
    $prefixesInArray = explode(',', $prefixes);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($prefixesInArray); i++) {
        if (count($prefixesInArray[$i]) <= count($word)) {
            if ($prefixesInArray[$i] == substr($word, 0, count($prefixesInArray[$i]))) {
               return True;
            }
        }
    }
    return False
}
```

This checks if the any of the prefixes are a prefix of the word given in `O(mn)` time where `m` is the max length of some prefix in the array given. It is also the fastest and most space optimal solution that can be found.

As it seems you weren't asking for a theoretical/CS question, there are other interesting ways to implement this in other data structures which can yield better runtimes if you do this repeatedly.

Comment: Why you used `if (count($prefixesInArray[$i]) <= count($word)) {` ?

Comment: replace `count` with `strlen` in `if ($prefixesInArray[$i] == substr($word, 0, count($prefixesInArray[$i]))) {`

Comment: I think you need to replace count with strlen in `if (count($prefixesInArray[$i]) <= count($word)) {` too.